# Fastest way to match two large arrays of objects by key in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two powershell arrays of objects generated via Import-CSV, and I must match them by one of their properties. Specifically, it is a 1:n relationship so currently I'm following this pattern:

```
foreach ($line in $array1) {
    $match=$array2 | where {$_.key -eq $line.key} # could be 1 or n results
    ...# process here the 1 to n lines
}
```

, which is not very efficient (both tables have many columns) and takes a time that is unacceptable for our needs. Is there a fastest way to perform this match?

Both data sources come from a csv file, so using something instead of Import-CSV would be also welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Actually, the time taken to do the Import-CSV is not very relevant, as it is under 10 seconds for about 7k rows, "one shot". The problem comes once the two powershell variables are loaded, as the match performed with the where clause takes 0,34 seconds

Comment: Can't you Group-Object your $array2 by key, then iterate from keys in $array1 to enumerate the corresponding results? My guess is that group-object would be faster than anything you would implement yourself in PowerShell, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard method is to index the data using a hashtable (or dictionary/map in other languages).

```
function buildIndex($csv, [string]$keyName) {
    $index = @{}
    foreach ($row in $csv) {
        $key = $row.($keyName)
        $data = $index[$key]
        if ($data -is [Collections.ArrayList]) {
            $data.add($row) >$null
        } elseif ($data) {
            $index[$key] = [Collections.ArrayList]@($data, $row)
        } else {
            $index[$key] = $row
        }
    }
    $index
}
```

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv 'r:\1.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv 'r:\2.csv'

$index2 = buildIndex $csv2, 'key'

foreach ($row in $csv1) {
    $matchedInCsv2 = $index2[$row.key]
    foreach ($row2 in $matchedInCsv2) {
        # ........
    }
}
```

Also, if you need speed and iterate a big collection, avoid `|` pipelining as it's many times slower than foreach/while/do *statements*. And don't use anything with a ScriptBlock like `where {$_.key -eq $line.key}` in your code because execution context creation adds a ridiculously big overhead compared to the simple code inside.

Comment: excellent and complete answer... I'll do some tests and post here the results.Thanks!

Comment: If it's likely one file is significantly smaller than the other, you can further optimize by selecting the smaller to index.  Perhaps by checking file length.

Comment: wow! a simple test with this technique goes from 170ms per item to 4ms !!!!. Thanks again